# Making a reliable UDP by socket function in c

Tags: c

I am having this doubt in socket programming which I could not get cleared by reading the man pages.

In c the declaration of socket function is `int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);`

The linux man page says that while type decides the stream that will be followed the protocol number is the one that decides the protocol being followed.

So my question is that suppose I give the type parameter as `SOCK_STREAM` which is reliable and add the protocol number for UDP would it give me a reliable UDP which is same as TCP but without flow control and congestion control.

Unfortunately I can't test this out as I have a single machine so there is no packet loss happening.

Could anyone clear this doubt? Thanks a lot...

Comment: By protocol number, do you mean port number?

Comment: @Macke: lower-level protocols such as UDP are also identified by number. See `socket(2)`.

Comment: @Macke No I do not ... You can have a look at this http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket where it mentions protocol number

Comment: @user506710: Ok. Thanks. It doesn't say what the choices are though, but I found somewhere else that it essentially is a choice between TCP/IP, unix-sockets and some other transports. Seems like there is no specific UDP number. Also, UDP/TCP can't be mixed like that, hence my confusion and my slightly misdirected answer (now deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For an IPV4 or IPV6 protocol stack, SOCK_STREAM is going to get you TCP and the type SOCK_DGRAM is going to give you UDP. The protocol parameter is not used for either of the choices and the socket library is typically expecting a value of 0 to be specified there.

Comment: The socket library is simply expecting to see the 0 as the protocol value, but this is not "controlling" anything per se'. If you want to change the properties of TCP protocol operations, like disabling the NAGLE algorithm, etc. do this after you create the socket using setsockopt(). See this for an overview: http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I chose this answer as it is what cleared the exact doubt that I had ...

Comment: Note that you can get reliable datagrams on many *nix'es through the SCTP protocol.

Answer (score 3):

UDP cannot be made reliable. Transmission of the packets is done on a "best effort" capacity, but any router/host along the chain is free to drop the packet in the garbage and NOT inform the sender that it has done so.

That's not to say you can't impose extra semantics on the sending and receiving ends to expect packets within a certain time frame and say "hey, we didn't get anything in the last X seconds". But that can't be done at the protocol level. UDP is a "dump it into the outbox and hope it gets there" protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I know what UDP does. What I meant was that adding the socket call like this does it ensure that packet reliability feature is added above UDP...

Comment: Like I said, you can't add the flag to UDP - it'll be ignored or cause an error condition. There's nothing you can do at the protocol level to make UDP reliable. It's inherently an unreliable protocol, which is why it's nickname is "Unreliable Datagram Protocol"

Comment: I actually thought that was really what UDP stood for.

Comment: officially, it's "User Datagram Protocol"

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_UDP):
```

socket() will return -1 and sett errno to

```
EPROTONOSUPPORT
          The protocol type or the specified protocol
          is not supported within    this domain.
```